# Hide the date part on a DateTime field MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, datetime, dynamics-crm-2011

I would like to have a time-only field on my CRM form (MS Dynamics CRM 2011). As it is apparently not possible, I plan to use a `DateTime` field and hide the date part.

How can I hide the date part on a `DateTime` field using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A supported method would be to instead create a new attribute on the entity (a text field called Time) and put that on the form.  Take your current DateTime field on the form, make it invisible, then use a Javascript event on the on the onChange event of the form to validate that it is a valid time.

Then in the onSave event of the form, copy the time over to the Date Time attribute that is hidden on the form (also remember to mark it as `Force Submit Always`).

That way the user won't be forced to pick a day (although the time selection will be arguably more difficult)

Comment: i think this is not good practice because user can set the values varies types

Comment: @AmilaRukshan not sure what you mean by "set the value varies types".  You do have to create and add Javascript to validate the the time entered is a valid time though.

Comment: yes it's good to  add Javascript to validate the the time  , thank for help

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set the date 
document.getElementById("field_name").DataValue = new Date(2000, 1, 1);
// Hide the date part
document.getElementById("field_name").childNodes[0].childNodes[0].style.display =
    "none";
document.getElementById("field_name").childNodes[0].childNodes[1].style.display =
    "none";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var DateTimeA = new Date();
var temp = DateTimeA.Split("/");
DateTimeA = temp[0];
```

Example of using a part of a date...

Comment: I want to hide date field not get date

Comment: use $(#DateTime_id).hide();

Comment: $("#DateTime_id").hide();